# Flutter AutoTabsRoute.pageview child not changes (auto_route)

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I'm using the [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package for routing in my app. I want to use the `AutoTabsRoute.pageview` widget to create Scaffold with routing tabs.

I don't know why, but the builder should return a different child each time, but it produces the same child. For that reason, **the selected tab changes, while the body does not.**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
return AutoTabsRouter.pageView(
  routes: const [
    MainRoute(),
    MaintenanceRoute(),
    PaymentsRoute(),
  ],
  builder: (context, child, _) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(context.topRoute.name),
        leading: const AutoLeadingButton(),
      ),
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) =>
            context.read<MenuCubit>().setTab(MenuTabs.values[index]),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Main',
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Maintenance',
            icon: Icon(Icons.work),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Payment',
            icon: Icon(Icons.payment),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue solved!

If you want the `child` parameter to change, you have to config:

```
final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
```

inside the builder, and update the index using it only:

```
onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex
```

**Full example:**

```
return AutoTabsRouter.pageView(
  routes: const [
    MainRoute(),
    MaintenanceRoute(),
    PaymentsRoute(),
  ],
  builder: (context, child, _) {
    final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context); // <--- configure the AutoTabsRouter parameter

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home365'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex, <--- use it here
        onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex, <--- use it here
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Main',
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Maintenance',
            icon: Icon(Icons.work),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Payment',
            icon: Icon(Icons.payment),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```